# Does unity gain Sallen-Key filter fulfill Bessel filter approximation?

Tags: analog, filter, active-filter

I want to apply a bandpass filter on my IR receiver. The signal generated on the IR receiver is a square wave so I was thinking of applying a Bessel filter on it. For unity gain, the Q value is 0.5 according to [this online source](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/filter/sallen-key-filter.html) and the frequency response looks like a Bessel filter. So it would be helpful if I get some clarification.

Does unity gain Sallen-Key filter fulfill Bessel filter approximation?

Comment: You must define your design specs for error rate, SNR , interference levels for bandstop rejection and budget for ISI jitter due to the filter for your carrier , modulation type and data rate. Otherwise the filter design is meaningless.  Sometimes referred to as an XY question.  If not critical then a low Q BPF is used. If high performance then you would choose Raised Cosine BPF filter

Comment: Did you understand?

Comment: Did you speak about a second-order bandpass? In this case, there is jus one single response for different Q-values (selectivity). But you cannot discriminate between Butterworth, Bessel, etc. This applies to higher oder bandpass structures only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Q for a 2nd order Bessel filter is fixed: 0.577 (or √⅓), what you're showing is for a critically damped 2nd order. However, Bessel filters are lowpass. Frequency transformations may be possible, but all bets are off. If you expect a bandpass to have no overshoot, think again, as a bandpass is not a lowpass: it cancels the DC. If you need clean pulses, then choose a lowpass. Here is the difference between a bandpass and a lowpass in terms of filtering a square wave (both filters chosen for the same fc as the square wave, a bit unusual):

[image: test]

Comment: As the q is fixed at 0.577 for Bessel, there should be a gain. Thanks for this info. I mainly want to remove Infrared noise (for example sunlight, TV remotes, etc) from my IR receiver. So low pass may not work. I was planning to switch the IR LED at 10-15 KHz and filter out this signal from the receiver. So, the conclusion is that Bessel won't work here. Isn't?

Comment: @SadatRafi If the noise is higher frequency, only, then a lowpass can be used. If the pulses are bipolar, then a bandpass *could* be used, if you don't care about waveform shape; if they're not bipolar (as seen in the picture), you will need additional diode to cut the negative pulses. It won't matter much what filter it is, Bessel, Butterworth, Chebyshev, Cauer, but bandpass vs lowpass will. How those pulses look like and what you want filtered, that's what decides here.

Comment: Raffi I hope you are using the daylight blocking filter and BPF (Q=2) of the Sharp/Vishay part  with AGC , then no extra filter needed

Comment: Bessel Cauer Eliptical, Chebychev, Raised Cosine etc all are available in LP, HP and BF filters

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 Not my best English. I meant that it's bandpass vs lowpass that matters most, not bandpass Bessel, or bandpass Cauer, or lowpass Butterworth, etc (though Cauer vs Bessel will obviously not be the same).

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can implement a bessel filter with sallen key topology of opamp(s). There are also other filter toplogies that you could potentially make a bessel filter from opamps and passives There are a few calculators [among them this one](https://www.daycounter.com/Filters/Sallen-Key-LP-Calculator.phtml) that can help calculate passive component values for the sallen key filter.

You might not be able to get the Q (physical components are lossy which reduces Q) you want out of a physical implementation so keep that in mind. But you can find the transfer function and plot the response and see if the approximation is acceptable.